# Order of reactivity towards nucleophilic reagents considering alkyl halogenides, acyl halides and aromatic halogenides

Tags: organic-chemistry

Considering alkyl halogenides (1°,2°,3°,4°), acyl halides, and aromatic halogenides and their combiations what is the order of reactivity towards nucleophilic reagents and why (considering inductive effect, mesomeric effect, etc.)? I know its a basic question that I could have searched for but I didn't find a source that compares all of the above.